# groovy oracle result capital column name issue

Tags: sql, oracle, groovy

In Groovy to set a bean you just need to give the GroovyRowResult while creating object.

Consider below People.groovy bean:

```
class People {
    String name
    int age
}
```

My sql query:

```
select * from People -- returns name and age of people
```

the GroovyRowResult is returned with column names (keys) in capitals like it:[NAME:"Alex", AGE: 21].
So when I try to set the bean like below:

```
le.rows(sqlQuery).each {
    People p = new People(it)
}
```

I receive the Exception: 
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: NAME for class: People. Possible solutions: name`

I guess I can modify sql query to include double quotes on the alias, but have you guys handled it any different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *rows()* method returns a `List<GroovyRowResult>` where `GroovyRowResult` implements `Map` and then you can apply `collectEntries` to transform it, so that the keys are lowercase and you can use the resulting map:

```
sql.rows('select * from people').each {
    People p = new People(it.collectEntries { k,v -> [k.toLowerCase(), v] })    
    println p.name
    println p.age
}
```